# Ruby one-liner and warning: 'else without rescue is useless'

Tags: ruby, algorithm, function, if-statement

I'm trying to print a basic triangle pattern with a Ruby function which only accepts positive odd number for n

```
def triangle(n, chars)
    puts "#{n} must be odd and positive" if n % 2 == 0 || n < 0 else (n + 1).times { |i| puts chars * i } 
end
```

The problem is this function accepts not only odd but also positive n. 
`triangle(3, '#')`would print

```
    #
    ##
    ###
```

but 'triangle(4, '#')' also works fine

```
    #
    ##
    ###
    ####
```

It seems my *if* statement is not working correctly and I get the warning `else without rescue is useless`. Why and how should I fix this?

Comment: If you need to use the trailing `if` or `unless` clause, try and keep it as simple as possible. For example: `next if (...)` is fine, but anything longer deserves the block-style use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby is interpreting your code as two separate statements.

```
puts "#{n} must be odd and positive" if n % 2 == 0 || n < 0

else (n + 1).times { |i| puts chars * i }
```

The `else` is not associated with the `if`. Ruby is, I guess in desperation, interpreting that as part of a [`begin/rescue/else` condition](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html). Why it's not a syntax error, I have no idea, but it's interpreting it as having no `begin` block which is technically "successful" so the `else` always runs.

Conditional statements like `do this if that` are intended only for simple conditions covering simple statements. Trying to wedge in an else condition is right out. Instead, use a normal condition.

```
def triangle(n, chars)
    if n % 2 == 0 || n < 0
        puts "#{n} must be odd and positive"    
    else
        (n + 1).times { |i| puts chars * i } 
    end
end
```

In general, avoid the `else` entirely by taking care of the error condition immediately. It avoids nesting the bulk of the function in an `else` block. This is more relevant for longer functions, but it's a good habit to get into.

```
def triangle(n, chars)
    if n % 2 == 0 || n < 0
        puts "#{n} must be odd and positive"
        return nil
    end

    (n + 1).times { |i| puts chars * i } 
end
```

Finally, errors should be handled with exceptions, not printed error messages. Exceptions can be caught and dealt with by the caller, printed error messages are difficult to catch and bubble up to the user. Exceptions, if not dealt with, halt the program; if the user forgets to handle an error the program will stop and they'll know to fix it. Printed error messages simply let the program plow forward and can be ignored leading to further problems down the road.

Exceptions can also be categorized allowing the caller to figure out what sort of error happened and act appropriately.

```
def triangle(n, chars)
    if n % 2 == 0 || n < 0
        raise ArgumentError, "#{n} must be odd and positive"
    end

    (n + 1).times { |i| puts chars * i } 
end
```

Comment: You could change this to return puts blah blah if condition because puts returns nil any way

Comment: @engineersmnky I'd hesitate to do that. I doubt most folks know what `puts` returns (I would assume a boolean). It also smashes together two otherwise unrelated statements just because one happens to return the needed value; we're not returning the result of `puts`, and the reader will wonder why. Vertical whitespace should be used where appropriate for clarity.

Comment: To each there own I tend to try and use a single line guard clause wherever possible rather than explicit early return. Seems more in line with style specifications (my opinion). Either way I agree with ArgumentError over the other implementations as it is more explicit and informative

Comment: "Why it's not a syntax error, I have no idea" – Well, because it's perfectly legal syntax. Method, block, and lambda bodies form an implicit `begin` block. `def foo() bar if baz else quux end` is equivalent to `def foo() begin bar if baz rescue StandardError else quux end end`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the flow control is getting confused with the logic as to what is output. This will do what you want, I think:

```
def triangle(n, chars)
  if (n % 2 == 0) || (n < 0)
    puts "#{n} must be odd and positive"
  else
    (n + 1).times { |i| puts chars * i }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more graceful implementation lets take this a step further and handle unexpected arguments

```
def triangle(n, chars='#')
  raise(ArgumentError, "{n} must be odd and positive") unless n.to_i.odd? && n.to_i > 0
  1.upto(n.to_i) { |i| chars.to_s * i} 
end
```

This will now handle any `n` that responds to `to_i` and any `chars` that responds to `to_s`. e.g. '13', ['x', 'x', 1] are still valid arguments even if they make a weird triangle.

Ruby is extremely supportive of duck typing in this fashion and it makes your code less type specific.